# test ActiveModel::Serializer that has a variable without using the controller tester

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an ActiveModel::Serializer class (class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer) that I'm looking to test. 
The serializer makes use of the current_user object, because it's in scope during the controller actions.

But I'm attempting to write a new rspec file. (task_serializer_spec.rb)

When I run

```
TaskSerializer.new(task).to_json
```

I get an error saying that the current_user method doesn't exist.

I can't mock the variable because we have "the method must exist" flag on our mocks.

I understand that there are some other parameters that I can pass in the NEW. but I can't find any docs on it.  Can someone offer a way to get things like current_user in the scope.

Answer (score 4):

My answer might be a little late, but if someone ever ends up on this page, here is a way to do this:

`app/serializers/task_serializer.rb` :

```
class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :method_using_current_user, :whatever_other_attributes_goes_here

  delegate :current_user, to: :scope

  def method_using_current_user
    current_user.some_method_here
  end
 end
```

In your rspec test, you can than do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe TaskSerializer do

  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  # or any other user you want to create here

  before do
    # As current user is delegated to controller scope, we mock both here
    allow_any_instance_of(TaskSerializer).to  receive(:scope).and_return(ApplicationController.new)
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  end

  # your test goes here
end
```

And voila.